# Im getting this error "Graph is finalized and cannot be modified." when i try to run the code

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
fitted = cnn_small_bn.fit(X_train, dummy_y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

Error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-caf630db0238> in <module>()
----> 1 fitted = cnn_small_bn.fit(X_train, dummy_y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _check_not_finalized(self)
   3345     """
   3346     if self._finalized:
-> 3347       raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
   3348 
   3349   def _add_op(self, op, op_name):

RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please share sample code to reproduce the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This Runtime error is caused mainly because MonitoredTrainingSession has **frozen** the graph and the `tf.global_variable_initializer()` can no longer modify it.

The functions mentioned are with respect to the version your code is referring to.

Please check this [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L243) which will give you an idea about how MonitoredTrainingSession is supposed to be used.

You can initialize the graph on loop, by using the function to create new graph on top of loop.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.Graph().as_default()
```

With the new version of tensorflow, these functions have a different representation as given in the migration guide. But the current code will work for your version.